How to show child term on click of parent term in facet?
I am using facets and I need one facet with Parent term taxonomy and when clicking on one parent term, another facet to appear with the children of the clicked parent taxonomy term.
Show child terms only on click of parent term accordingly.
How should I achieve this? Thank in advance.
eg.

   Parent A (If I clicked on then only shows child terms)
     - Child 1
     - Child 2
  Parent n
     - Child n
 
